# How to minimize size of composer download?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm using composer to download two packages like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "propel/propel1": "1.6.9",
        "smarty/smarty": "v3.1.14"
    }
}
```

Now for example this smarty package is loading whole svn repository (not only files) and just the `.svn` folder weights 12MB. It also loads documentation and bunch of other files that can be useful in development, but have no right to be part of the production environment.

My question is - is there a way to install packages only with files that are libraries needed to run the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen a fragment in the [composer documentation](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories), and for the most current version 3.1.14, this works and downloads the ZIP file blazingly fast:

```
{
    "require": {
        "smarty/smarty" : "3.1.14"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "smarty/smarty",
                "version": "3.1.14",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "http://www.smarty.net/files/Smarty-3.1.14.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                },
                "source": {
                    "url": "http://smarty-php.googlecode.com/svn/",
                    "type": "svn",
                    "reference": "tags/Smarty_3_1_14/distribution/"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately Smarty seems to NOT maintain such info, so you are on your own when updating it, but I think it should enable you to switch from that nasty SVN download to getting the released ZIP file distribution if you adjust the paths a little bit, and probably add `--prefer-dist` to your composer install call.

Comment: Despite use of --prefer-dist it's still loading it from SVN.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I haven't tested it yet. You might want to try add an issue report to make the smarty maintainers add download info to their software, but this would only be working long-term.

Comment: Ok, I have tested it, and it works for me. See my updated answer with the json I used.

Comment: You should probably remove the smarty downloaded via SVN and start fresh. Delete the whole vendor directory and install or update again with the changed composer.json.

Comment: I thought it will just require me to run composer with --prefer-dist, but adding this repositories section is mendatory too... I added it and it works now. Thanks.